# Changing class of a div using parent's id - jquery

Tags: jquery

In my page there is an `<a>` tag and inside that there is a `<div>`. that is shown below:

```
 <a id="test"  title="Change Color Code" href="#" class="modalDlg">
     <div class="<%:(colorCode) %>">

     </div>
 </a>
```

How can i change the class of `<div>` when i click on another button in that page ( i only have the id of the hyperlink (ie , test ) ).

Can i change the class of that `<div>` using the hyperlink id (which contains that div) using jquery ?

Comment: are you wanting to change the class (as in replace the current value) or add more classes (e.g. <div class="class1 class2">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple way to do this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#test div').addClass('foo');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("<YOUR_BUTTON_SELECTOR>").click(function(){
    $("#test div").addClass("<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>");
    // OR $("#test div").removeClass("<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>");
});
```

Comment: or `$('#test div')[0].className = '<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>';` if you just want to set it to something.